# download image from api

Tags: android

Please help me to download the image from api dynamically in android app??

**ImageLoader.java**

```
package com.solodroid.ecommerce;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    Handler handler=new Handler();//handler to display images in UI thread

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }


    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1e1411"));
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Constant.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,o);
            stream1.close();

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            FileInputStream stream2=new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u;
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                handler.post(bd);
            }catch(Throwable th){
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

Please tell me the mistake or tell me how to download image from the api in the android app?It will be good if you are able to find out one.I have to download the image dynamically coming from the api using PHP. Please help me out over this.

Comment: you can upload **to** api, or download **from** api, not upload **from** api. What do you want to do? Upload or download

Comment: @VladMatvienko download from api

Comment: I think you should use one of the libraries made for image loading like Picasso, or Universal Image Loader.

Comment: But how can i use it ?

Comment: there is very simple tutorial on the main page of the project. http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: ok thanku so much...

Comment: use glide library to load image from url , it is effecient  in comparison of picasso

Comment: @jatDevta: Sir can you tell me what the error in the code why the image is not displayed in that place..

Comment: @IshaGupta no need to store bitmap , just store the url of image , using Glide frame work show them in the ImageView , as Malik Abu Qaoud already gave the answer , how to use glide in android

Comment: but i cannt get the proper use of this ?? please elaborate it

Answer (score 0):

In your bulid.gradle(Module.app) add this

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'   
}
```

and in your activity add this line

```
Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
```

Comment: and tyr to search about Glide it's great library and has a lot of features